# SSL installed but no lock display in the web browser

Tags: ssl

I have installed SSL on a server. When I try links using https they work, but I don't see a lock. Any suggestion on the issue?

Comment: Which browser are you in?

Comment: firefox 3.6 I see locks for other sites.

Answer (score 1):

You said you're using Firefox.  Right click on the page, and select `View Page Info`.  Then click on security.  What is the output?

I also like to use the OpenSSL command line to check my SSL servers:

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443
```

Comment: Steven , when i do view page info , i see that a certificate is there . But when i run openssl command then i get return code :21 unable to verify first certificate.

Comment: That error can be ignored because OpenSSL can't verify the certificate unless you specify a root store. If OpenSSL can see the certificate, it should be installed. Do you see a lock icon with an slash through it? This indicates that an image or script is being loaded from http instead of https.

Comment: i can see the lock when i use the domain name instead of ip address.